# Как сделать, чтобы считывания вопросов с .txt файла были в рандомно порядке?

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема заключается в том, что мне нужно сделать рандомно считывания и вывод вопросов с .txt файла. Сейчас у меня все вопросы идут по очереди. Для каждого вопроса у меня в файле выделяется 6 строк (1 - вопрос, 2-5 - ответы, 6 - правильный ответ).

```
void Begining()
        {
            var Кодирования= System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
            try
            {
                // Создание экземпляра StreamReader для чтения из файла
                Reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
                this.Text = Reader.ReadLine(); // Название теста
            }
            catch (Exception Event)
            {   // Звіт про всі помилки:
                MessageBox.Show(Event.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
            NextQuestion();
        } 

 void NextQuestion()
        {
            label1.Text = Reader.ReadLine();
            // Считывания вариантов ответа:
            radioButton1.Text = Reader.ReadLine();
            radioButton2.Text = Reader.ReadLine();
            radioButton3.Text = Reader.ReadLine();
            radioButton4.Text = Reader.ReadLine();
            // Определение правильного ответа:
            NRA = int.Parse(Reader.ReadLine()); 
        }
```

Comment: Считайте все вопросы в память, потом в памяти их перемешайте и выводите в перемешанном порядке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попытаюсь просто, вводя минимум новых непонятных слов в пример и добавлю чуть-чуть обучающей информации.

1) Создайте класс, который будет хранить вопрос и все ответы

```csharp
public class QuestionItem
{
    public string Question { get; set; } // Так описывается свойство объекта
    public string Radio1 { get; set; } // Почитайте про свойства, поля и чем они отличаются
    public string Radio2 { get; set; }
    public string Radio3 { get; set; }
    public string Radio4 { get; set; }
    public int Answer { get; set; }
}
```

2) Создайте список с вопросами

```csharp
List<QuestionItem> questions = new List<QuestionItem>();
```

3) Загрузите весь файл в строку

***ВНИМАНИЕ!*** Файл должен быть в кодировке **UTF-8**, забудьте про кодировку Win-1251 как про пережиток прошлого времён Windows XP. Если файл не перекодирован, его можно перекодировать, например с помощью текстового редактора `Notepad++`.

```csharp
string text;
try
{
    text = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt"); // вот так просто
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка при чтении файла");
}
// и сразу можно разбить загруженный текст на строки,
// пустые строки автоматически при этом удалятся
string[] lines = text.Split(new[] { '\r', '\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

или еще предлагают вот так

```csharp
string[] lines;
try
{
    lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка при чтении файла");
}
```

4) Загрузите вопросы из массива строк в список вопросов

```csharp
int questionsCount = lines.Length / 6; // вопросов в 6 раз меньше, чем строк
for (int i = 0; i < questionsCount; i++) 
{
    int offset = i * 6; // номер первой строки с вопросом
    QuestionItem question = new QuestionItem(); // новый вопрос
    question.Question = lines[offset];
    question.Radio1 = lines[offset + 1];
    question.Radio2 = lines[offset + 2];
    question.Radio3 = lines[offset + 3];
    question.Radio4 = lines[offset + 4];
    question.Answer = int.TryParse(lines[offset + 5], out int answer) ? answer : 0; // 0 - значение на случай если произошла ошибка превращения строки в число
    questions.Add(question); // добавить вопрос в список
}
```

5) Теперь можно получить случайный вопрос с помощью генератора случайных чисел

```
Random rndGenerator = new Random(); // это можно создать один раз при загрузке программы

// ...

int n = rndGenerator.Next(questions.Count()); // n - порядковый номер вопроса
QuestionItem q = questions[n]; // вот он, случайный вопрос!

// дальше ваш код
label1.Text = q.Question;

radioButton1.Text = q.Radio1;
radioButton2.Text = q.Radio2;
radioButton3.Text = q.Radio3;
radioButton4.Text = q.Radio4;

NRA = q.Answer;
```

Я умышленно не сделал следующие вещи, но вам советую с этим разобраться:

- Список вариантов ответов лучше хранить массивом `string[]`, доработайте код
- Поддержка динамического количества ответов на один вопрос была бы очень кстати, например 3 ответа, или 6

Comment: Обращу внимание на пункт 3: Все это можно сделать в одну строчку: `lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");`

Comment: @AndreiKhotko спасибо, но оно не удалит пустые строки :) Добавил в ответ.

Comment: Действительно, не дочитал последнюю строчку до конца, прошу прощения.Тогда можно так: `File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt").Where(p => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(p));`. И там уже можно или в List, или в Array :)

Comment: @AndreiKhotko в условии задачи про пустые строки не было, это скорее опция, оставим на усмотрение автора вопроса. LINQ - это сурово. :)