# Как сделать тест на c# WinForm

Tags: c#, windows

Нужно написать программу для тестирования с использование RadioButton-ов.
Есть один label, три RB и две кнопки: "следующий вопрос" и "завершить".

Как можно считать в файле, что к примеру название теста будет символом #, а вопросы @ и правильный ответ $.

Comment: Попробуйте сначала сами, а потом, приходите сюда с тем, что у вас не получается реализовать, показав нам ваши попытки. Ибо сейчас вопрос ваш звучит как: "Как мне кушать? Нужно взять ложку, но что приготовить на ужин?".

Comment: [Был такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1110960/373567)

Comment: считывать строки в файле можно через `File.ReadAllLines`, к примеру. Для начала вам нужно определиться со структурой файла. Я вижу структуру так: `{ вопрос_1 [текст_ответа_1, правильность], [текст_ответа_2, правильность]... }...`. Эту структуру можно оформить как угодно, хоть чераз json, как в моём примере, хоть через xml, хоть через собственный формат

Comment: [Еще вот такой вопрос был](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280658/373567), там WPF, относительно этого вопроса разницы нет.

Answer (score 0):

Заводите классы:

```
class Test {}
class Answer : RadioButton {}
class Question : GroupBox {}
```

Создаёте: `List<Test>, List<Question>`
При чтении обходите string[] из файла, и в зависимости от начального символа #@$ создаёте необходимый вам экземпляр класса и добавляете его в нужный список/нужный класс.
Далее упорядочиваете контролы Answer(RadioButton) и Question(GroupBox) меняя их координаты, и если нужно меняете их размеры в зависимости от кол-ва вариантов ответа, размещаете Question'ы на форме/табах/панелях, где ходите...
При завершении тестирования - обходите списки List, проверяя правильные ответы.